# Javascript NETMASK and CIDR conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was expecting to find hundreds of examples of functions to convert to and from CIDR and NETMASK for javascript, but was unable to find any.

I need to convert to and from CIDR and NETMASKS on a nodejs page which sets and retrieves the IP address for a machine using NETCTL.

Any easy solutions to do this using javascript / nodejs ??

Answer (score 6):

Here's one that doesn't check if the netmask is valid:

```
const netmaskToCidr = n => n
  .split('.')
  .reduce((c, o) => c - Math.log2(256 - +o), 32)
```

Answer (score 4):

This code could provide a solution:

```
var mask = "255.255.248.0";
var maskNodes = mask.match(/(\d+)/g);
var cidr = 0;
for(var i in maskNodes)
{
  cidr += (((maskNodes[i] >>> 0).toString(2)).match(/1/g) || []).length;
}
return cidr;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    NETMASK                        BINARY               CIDR
255.255.248.0       11111111.11111111.11111000.00000000 /21
255.255.0.0         11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000 /16 
255.192.0.0         11111111.11000000.00000000.00000000 /10
```

This how calculate CIDR.. So , it is the occurrences of `1`  in the second cloumn. Thus , I design a readable algorithm as below :

```js
const masks = ['255.255.255.224', '255.255.192.0', '255.0.0.0']; 
/**
* Count char in string
*/
const countCharOccurences = (string , char) => string.split(char).length - 1;

const decimalToBinary = (dec) => (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
const getNetMaskParts = (nmask) => nmask.split('.').map(Number);
const netmask2CIDR = (netmask) => 
   countCharOccurences(
     getNetMaskParts(netmask)
      .map(part => decimalToBinary(part))
      .join(''),
    '1'   
  );    


masks.forEach((mask) => {
  console.log(`Netmask =${mask}, CIDR = ${netmask2CIDR(mask)}`)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been long since this question was asked, but I just wanted to add checks to ensure that the netmask is valid:

```
function mask2cidr(mask){
    var cidr = ''
    for (m of mask.split('.')) {
        if (parseInt(m)>255) {throw 'ERROR: Invalid Netmask'} // Check each group is 0-255
        if (parseInt(m)>0 && parseInt(m)<128) {throw 'ERROR: Invalid Netmask'}

        cidr+=(m >>> 0).toString(2)
    }
    // Condition to check for validity of the netmask
    if (cidr.substring(cidr.search('0'),32).search('1') !== -1) {
        throw 'ERROR: Invalid Netmask ' + mask
    }
    return cidr.split('1').length-1
}
```

As the mask is only valid when the bits in 1 go from left to right, the condition checks that no bit is 1 after the first bit in 0. It also checks each group is 0 or 128-255

The method of conversion is mostly the same as the other answers

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have mentioned using node.js to implement this, I'm assuming you're looking for a way to run this server side in javascript, as opposed to client side. If that's correct, does the [netmask](https://github.com/rs/node-netmask) npm module cover what you need to do?